# Unable to install bower on Openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift, bower

I am unable to install bower on Openshift. I keep on getting errors like

```
remote: npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/var/lib/openshift/537xxxxcd/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mout/array/intersection.js'[K
remote: npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:[K
remote: npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>[K
remote: npm ERR! or email it to:[K
remote: npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>[K
```

You can see full deployment logs https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/26291843/log.txt [From travis here].

I tried several approaches:
1) with and without .bowerrc file

case:1

```
{
    "directory": "~/app-root/runtime/repo/public/libs"
    "storage": {
            "cache": "~/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/cache",
            "completion": "~/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/completion",
            "git": "~/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/git_template"
    },
    "interactive": "false",
    "tmp":"~/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/tmp",
    "cwd":"~/app-root/runtime/repo"
}
```

case:2

```
{
    "directory": "public libs"
}
```

Also, tried running following commands [In $HOME/app-root/runtime/repo] and tried npm install bower by SSH shell

```
 npm cache clear
 npm cache clean
```

Any help to resolve this would be great.

In case you want to look at my repo you can find it here:  https://github.com/prasunsultania/demoblog

Comment: It appears to me that it is a version compatibility issue between bower and npm engine. npm version is 1.2.17 on Openshift and other platforms like Heroku and Cloudcontrol are on 1.4.x, there bower install works like a charm. Is there a way in Openshift to upgrade npm engine?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is how I made use of `bower` on OpenShift using the node.js cartridge:

Prerequisites:

- Usually you have installed Bower globally.
- The git repo which you push to OpenShift must be readily configured for using Bower so that `bower install` from the root of the repo will do the job.

Necessary steps:

1. Create the file `.openshift/action_hooks/deploy`
2. Do `chmod +x .openshift/action_hooks/deploy` to make it executable BEFORE you add and commit it to your repo
3. Add the following lines to the file:

`#!/usr/bin/env bash`

```
HOME=$HOME/app-root/runtime
cd ~/repo
npm install bower
./node_modules/.bin/bower install
```

4. Add and commit the file to your git repo
5. Push your git repo to OpenShift

Comment: If you are on a windows PC you will need to run: git update-index --chmod=+x .openshift/action_hooks/deploy instead of chmod +x .openshift/action_hooks/deploy

Answer (score 6):

[This](http://ambracode.com/index/show/49308) suggests the following approach:

1. Add dependency `"bower": "latest"` to `package.json`
2. Add script for postinstall:

   ```
   "scripts": {  
       ... 
       "postinstall": "HOME=$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR bower install || bower install"  
   },
   ```

Answer (score 0):

well, for each time you need to use `bower install`, you can use `export HOME=$HOME/app-root/runtime/repo` in the [RHC](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-client-tools.html) tool, and then into the folder './app-root/repo' you can use the `bower install`, if `bower` command is not available, go to folder './nodejs' and do `npm install bower`.

Then, in order with [RHC](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-client-tools.html) tool (this worked perfect to me):

- 1 - `rhc ssh proyect-name`
- 2 - `cd nodejs`
- 3 - `npm install bower`
- 4 - `cd ..`
- 5 - `export HOME=$HOME/app-root/runtime/repo`
- 6 - `cd app-root/repo`
- 7 - `bower install`

done! good luck with your projects