# Using Bower in Openshift Django

Tags: python, django, npm, openshift, bower

I have an app in Openshift with the cartridges  Python 2.7 and Mysql 5.5, I want to run a Django app on it. I used [this](https://github.com/rancavil/django-openshift-quickstart/wiki/Tutorial-How-create-an-application-with-Django-1.6-on-Openshift) to start building the app.

On local, I am using bower as package manager, so I've got installed django-bower, so I can make `./manage.py bower install`. I've also got installed bower globally:

```
>which bower
/usr/local/bin/bower
```

On local everything works fine, the problems come when I try to deploy in openshift. I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937675/unable-to-install-bower-on-openshift#answer-26643375) that bower should be installed in openshift but apparently, I don't have bower installed globally:

```
which: no bower in (/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa0438****47000094/python//virtenv/bin:/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa0438****47000094/python//bin:/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin)
```

So I am trying to install it running this:

```
export HOME=$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
cd $HOME
npm cache clear
npm cache clean
npm install bower --prefix $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
```

But it fails in the last command with this output:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.3.12.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.3.12.tgz
npm WARN engine bower@1.3.12: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0"} (current: {"node":"0.6.20","npm":"1.1.37"})
çnpm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/archy/0.0.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-config
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-endpoint-parser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-json
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-logger
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-registry-client
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk/0.5.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cardinal/0.4.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chmodr/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/decompress-zip/0.0.8
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream-ignore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/handlebars
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer/0.7.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/insight/0.4.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/is-root
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/junk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lockfile
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.5.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mout
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/opn
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/osenv/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/p-throttler/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/promptly/0.2.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/q
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request-progress/0.3.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/retry/0.6.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
[MORE OF THE SAME]
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod '/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js'
npm ERR!  { [Error: ENOENT, chmod '/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js']
npm ERR!   errno: 34,
npm ERR!   code: 'ENOENT',
npm ERR!   path: '/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js',
npm ERR!   fstream_finish_call: 'chmod',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'File',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'FileWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: [ 'Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19)' ] }
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "bower" "--prefix" "/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/"
npm ERR! cwd /var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.20
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.37
npm ERR! path /var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chmod
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! message ENOENT, chmod '/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js'
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19)
npm ERR! 34 errno
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client'
npm ERR! error rolling back  bower@1.3.12 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client' }
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: ansi-styles@'^1.1.0'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","0.2.0","1.0.0","1.1.0"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:588:10)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:466:15
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:136:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:230:7)
npm ERR!  [Error: No compatible version found: ansi-styles@'^1.1.0'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","0.2.0","1.0.0","1.1.0"]]
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "bower" "--prefix" "/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/"
npm ERR! cwd /var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.20
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.37
npm ERR! message No compatible version found: ansi-styles@'^1.1.0'
npm ERR! message Valid install targets:
npm ERR! message ["0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","0.2.0","1.0.0","1.1.0"]
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod '/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/rimraf/test/test-sync.js'
npm ERR!  { [Error: ENOENT, chmod '/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/rimraf/test/test-sync.js']
npm ERR!   errno: 34,
npm ERR!   code: 'ENOENT',
npm ERR!   path: '/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/rimraf/test/test-sync.js',
npm ERR!   fstream_finish_call: 'chmod',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'File',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/rimraf/test/test-sync.js',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'FileWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: [ 'Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19)' ] }
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "bower" "--prefix" "/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/"
npm ERR! cwd /var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.20
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.37
npm ERR! path /var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/rimraf/test/test-sync.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/rimraf/test/test-sync.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chmod
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! message ENOENT, chmod '/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/rimraf/test/test-sync.js'
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19)
npm ERR! 34 errno
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mout/string.js'
npm ERR!  { [Error: ENOENT, lstat '/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mout/string.js']
npm ERR!   errno: 34,
npm ERR!   code: 'ENOENT',
npm ERR!   path: '/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mout/string.js',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'File',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mout/string.js',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'FileWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: [ 'Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26)' ] }
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64
[MORE OF THE SAME]
npm ERR! 34 errno
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/lib/openshift/5425aaa04382ec0447000094/app-root/runtime/repo/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code undefined
npm ERR! not ok code 34
```

Any Ideas??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ssh into your gear and cd to `~/app-root/data/` and then run `npm install bower`. I was able to get it installed without any issues:

```
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/es6-symbol
bower@1.3.12 node_modules/bower
├── is-root@1.0.0
├── junk@1.0.0
├── stringify-object@1.0.0
├── which@1.0.5
├── abbrev@1.0.5
├── chmodr@0.1.0
├── osenv@0.1.0
├── opn@1.0.0
├── archy@0.0.2
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── lru-cache@2.5.0
├── bower-logger@0.2.2
├── bower-endpoint-parser@0.2.2
├── graceful-fs@3.0.4
├── lockfile@1.0.0
├── nopt@3.0.1
├── retry@0.6.0
├── tmp@0.0.23
├── q@1.0.1
├── semver@2.3.2
├── request-progress@0.3.0 (throttleit@0.0.2)
├── fstream@1.0.2 (inherits@2.0.1)
├── bower-json@0.4.0 (intersect@0.0.3, deep-extend@0.2.11, graceful-fs@2.0.3)
├── shell-quote@1.4.2 (array-filter@0.0.1, array-reduce@0.0.0, array-map@0.0.0, jsonify@0.0.0)
├── chalk@0.5.0 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.2, ansi-styles@1.1.0, supports-color@0.2.0, has-ansi@0.1.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0)
├── promptly@0.2.0 (read@1.0.5)
├── mkdirp@0.5.0 (minimist@0.0.8)
├── p-throttler@0.1.0 (q@0.9.7)
├── fstream-ignore@1.0.1 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@1.0.0)
├── glob@4.0.6 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@1.0.0, once@1.3.1)
├── bower-config@0.5.2 (osenv@0.0.3, graceful-fs@2.0.3, optimist@0.6.1)
├── tar-fs@0.5.2 (pump@0.3.5, tar-stream@0.4.7)
├── decompress-zip@0.0.8 (mkpath@0.1.0, nopt@2.2.1, touch@0.0.2, readable-stream@1.1.13, binary@0.3.0)
├── mout@0.9.1
├── request@2.42.0 (caseless@0.6.0, json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, stringstream@0.0.4, forever-agent@0.5.2, aws-sign2@0.5.0, oauth-sign@0.4.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, node-uuid@1.4.1, qs@1.2.2, mime-types@1.0.2, bl@0.9.3, tough-cookie@0.12.1, form-data@0.1.4, hawk@1.1.1, http-signature@0.10.0)
├── bower-registry-client@0.2.1 (graceful-fs@2.0.3, request-replay@0.2.0, lru-cache@2.3.1, async@0.2.10, mkdirp@0.3.5, request@2.27.0)
├── cardinal@0.4.0 (redeyed@0.4.4)
├── update-notifier@0.2.0 (semver-diff@0.1.0, string-length@0.1.2, latest-version@0.2.0, configstore@0.3.1)
├── handlebars@2.0.0 (optimist@0.3.7, uglify-js@2.3.6)
├── inquirer@0.7.1 (figures@1.3.3, mute-stream@0.0.4, through@2.3.6, readline2@0.1.0, lodash@2.4.1, rx@2.3.14, cli-color@0.3.2)
└── insight@0.4.3 (object-assign@1.0.0, async@0.9.0, chalk@0.5.1, lodash.debounce@2.4.1, os-name@1.0.1, tough-cookie@0.12.1, configstore@0.3.1, inquirer@0.6.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rhc ssh [PROJECT NAME]
cd nodejs
npm install bower
```